# Do trains run to Beni Nsar Port in Morocco?

Tags: train-stations, morocco

I'm planning a trip to Morocco next year, and I'm looking at the feasibility of getting from Melilla to Fes by train.  There's not station in Melilla, but Beni Nsar Port seems to be about a 20 minutes walk beyond the border.  Unfortunately, while Beni Nsar Port is listed as a station on the [ONCF (Moroccan Railways) website](https://www.oncf.ma/en/Horaires?), no services are listed, and [this undated blog post](https://www.wanderlust.co.uk/content/wander-woman-food-south-through-morocco/) suggests "the station that only exists on the internet".  However [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nador_railway_stations) suggests it does exist, and it is shown on [Open Railway Map](https://www.openrailwaymap.org/).  Does anyone know the true situation?  Is it just a temporarily closure?  Is it a bug in the ONCF system?  Or has the passenger service to Beni Nsar Port been discontinued?

I'm aware that Beni Nsar Ville and Nador Ville both have trains.